# Interactive php

Tags: php

I looking for interactive PHP application like LINQPad for C# where I can test code snippets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have PHP's CLI installed, just do `php -a` at the command line (preferably on an OS with a decent shell). This launches an interactive mode. Start with `<?php` and you're good to go.